# Adding ClickHandler to div which contains many other widget

Tags: gwt, uibinder

It seems that Panel doesn't inherit from HasClickHandlers and I can't add a clickHandler to DivElement.  Is there any way to add the clickHandler to a DIV?

EDIT:  The reason I can't use Label as that the DIV I want to be clickable contains other DIV.

Comment: You can use the Label widget. It uses a div element and implements HasClickHandlers.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

By default, Panel doesnt 'sink' the onCLick event. That is, clicking on Panels doesnt actually result into a 'ClickEvent' and hence the handler isnt fired. To use click events with Panel (or for that matter any other Widget) you must first invoke sinkEvents() on it with the appropriate event bits.

For example:

```
SimplePanel p = new SimplePanel();
    p.sinkEvents(Event.ONCLICK);
    p.setTitle("Click me");
    p.setSize("600px", "600px");
    p.addHandler(new ClickHandler(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {

            Window.alert("SimplePanel clicked!");

        }

    }, ClickEvent.getType());
```

The above piece of code first 'enables' click events for the SimplePanel using `p.sinkEvents(Event.ONCLICK);` and then goes on to add the standard ClickHandler onto it. Note that even though SimplePanel doesnt implement HasClickHandlers, you can always add a handler using the `addHandler()` method.

Comment: The sinkEvents solved my problem with SimplePanel that doesn't want to respond to clickEvents.

Comment: Call `addDomHandler` instead, and then you don't need to `sinkEvents`.

Answer (score 11):

Use the [`FocusPanel`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/1.5/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/FocusPanel.html).

> A simple panel that makes its contents focusable, and adds the ability to catch mouse and keyboard events.

Comment: My DIV contains several other widgets.  I can't use FocusPanel as it can only contain 1 widget.

Comment: That's not a problem: place your `<div>` containing several widgets inside the `FocusPanel`. Or is there a reason you can't do that?

Answer (score 7):

```
public class ClickableDiv extends FlowPanel implements HasClickHandlers {
    @Override
    public HandlerRegistration addClickHandler(ClickHandler handler) {
        return addDomHandler(handler, ClickEvent.getType());
    }
}
```

That should be all you need. `addDomHandler` will take care of "sinking" the event type for you.