# How to add a ClickListener on each single cell in a grid using GWT?

Tags: gwt, grid, clicklistener

How do I register a ClickListener on each single cell in a grid? I wanna make a timetable where the user can create appointments by clicking on a date.

Comment: Welcome to SO!  Please edit your question to include your code that you've tried so far so that we can better help you.  Otherwise, as it is currently stated, your question will likely be closed for being off-topic (see #3 on the off-topic question list on the [question topics help page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)).

Answer (score 0):

You can have a SimplePanel in each grid and add it a clickHandler with

addHandler()

as described here
[Adding ClickHandler to div which contains many other widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4303320/adding-clickhandler-to-div-which-contains-many-other-widget)